# sqlite3 simple query in python hangs

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm trying to make a simple query in python and sqlite3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-

import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
query = """CREATE TABLE `home` (
   `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
   `full_name` char(255) not null,
   `display_name` char(255),
   `ip_address` char(255) not null,
   `user`  char(255) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);"""
db.execute(query)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

But when i run the script, nothing happens; i mean: a file called test.db is created in the directory, but after that the shell remain there without return anything (even the prompt) and i need to kill the script with kill -9

Any help?

Comment: I get a `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "auto_increment": syntax error` exception instead. SQLite has `AUTOINCREMENT` *without* an underscore. Even with that corrected, there are more syntax errors still, because `AUTOINCREMENT` can *only* be used with a `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Comment: @JoelCornett: SQLite3 is pretty tolerant of other types, actually. `int` works just fine, but you probably don't want to use it if you can help it.

Comment: @JoelCornett: See the [type affinity documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); `char` has `TEXT` affinity, `int` is mostly aligned with `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your script apparently hangs, but there are SQL syntax errors in your query:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "auto_increment": syntax error
```

SQLite only have a [`AUTOINCREMENT`](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) keyword, and that only is supported after the [`PRIMARY KEY` constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint); you'll have to move your `PRIMARY KEY` line from the bottom to the `id` column. You'll have to use the proper `INTEGER` type as well, instead of `int`.

SQLite also ignores column sizes, you may as well drop those.

The following query works:

```
query = """CREATE TABLE `home` (
   `id` integer primary key autoincrement,
   `full_name` char(255) not null,
   `display_name` char(255),
   `ip_address` char(255) not null,
   `user`  char(255) not null
);"""
```

where I left in the column sizes for the `char` columns, but you may as well make those `TEXT` (without a size) and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks man! Now i know because script keep hanging: if a create it in a NFS share, it hangs! Why? No idea. The only thing i know is that on NFS share it create a regluar file and not a db file. :-O

Comment: SQLite requires proper locking to work, something NFS doesn't always support.